# Calculate integral curve through a discretely sampled vector field

Tags: approximation, vector-fields, approximation-theory

given a finite sample of a smooth vector field, i.e. a set
$$S=\{(p_i,v_i)\mid i\in \{1,\dots, n\}, p_i,v_i\in\mathbb{R}^2\}$$
where the $p_i$ are the points at which we have a vector $v_i$, how do I construct an integral curved through this vector field. I would guess there is no guarantee in general that such an integral curve would be unique, so I'm interested in a general method where I can supply an optimisation function and the set $S$, and from that compute an integral curve minimizing the optimisation function.

I would also be interested in ways of computing not an integral curve through such a field, but a transversal curve through such a field.

Any suggestions for papers/algorithms/methods of solving this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you essentially asking for a procedure to optimize (minimize) the length of the path through the points $p_i$? If so, from then on, the rest would just be a parametrized vector integral over the plane, ya? Or am I misinterpreting your question?